# Error when adding activated event to toast notification

Tags: c#, windows-8, toast

I have added a toast notification to my program, compiled it, and it works as expected.

The toast notification is shown.

After that I added the activated event:

```
toast.Activated += toast_Activated;

void toast_Activated(ToastNotification sender, object args)
{

}
```

When trying to compile this code I get following error:

> Property, indexer, or event
>   'Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification.Activated' is not
>   supported by the language; try directly calling accessor method
>   'Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification.add_Activated(Windows.Foundation.TypedEventHandler)'
>   or
>   'Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification.remove_Activated(System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.EventRegistrationToken)'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same problem when I was reproducing Sending toast notifications from desktop apps sample. After a few hours for checking all the differences with the sample, I found that I had mistakenly added reference to "System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" instead of "System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll". Changing the reference to the latter, it worked fine.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll